# How to get Papa.parse RECORD_SEP, UNIT_SEP to see what characters it autodetected

Tags: parsing, escaping, sequence

When parsing a csv file, how can I return the char used as an escape sequence character?

Comment: RECORD_SEP and UNIT_SEP are constants - they're ASCII codes 30 and 31. The escape character of CSV is a double quotation mark `"`.

Comment: Thanks, i saw those. Im busy with a program, where I need to parse different files and i need to be able to change the escape char, for incase the author didnt use " as a char but rather ' or something else. Or if papa parse detects it automatically, i need to know what it detected

Comment: It doesn't; Papa Parse requires that the input is adherent to the CSV specification, which specifies " as the quote escape character.